# Are there nontrivial continuous maps between complex projective spaces?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Are there maps $f: \Bbb{CP}^n \rightarrow \Bbb{CP}^m$, with $n>m$, that are not null-homotopic? In particular, is there some non-null-homotopic map $\Bbb{CP}^n \rightarrow S^2$ for $n>1$? Can we say anything more generally about the pairs $(n,m)$ that admit such maps?

Note that, in the real case, the answer to the first quesiton is yes and the second no: the Hopf map descends to a non-null-homotopic map $\Bbb{RP}^3 \rightarrow \Bbb{RP}^2$, and there's a natural bijection between $[\Bbb{RP}^n, S^1]$ and $H^1(\Bbb{RP}^n; \Bbb Z) = 0$.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915897/homotopical-classes-of-mappings-mathbbcpn-to-mathbbcpm) asks about the $n \leq m$ situation.

**Edit**: Jason DeVito's post below answers both questions in the affirmative; there remains, though, the following interesting case:

Is there a map $f: \Bbb{CP}^2 \rightarrow \Bbb{CP}^1$ that is not null-homotopic?

Comment: Thanks for asking such a fun question!  I just wanted to add that I'm interested in the following question:  is there *always* a nontrivial map between $\mathbb{C}P^n$ and $\mathbb{C}P^m$ for any $n$ and $m$?  By the linked question, we may assume $n\geq m$.  I'm willing to award a bounty, of, say, 500 pts if anyone ever answers it.  (I'm not putting a bounty on this now, because I suspect the answer is hard enough that it won't be solved in the bounty award time.)

Comment: @Jason I suspect the answer is false for similar reasons as the reason it's sometime true; the first step would be to find a bunch of trivial homotopy groups of spheres and fiddle with the appropriate dimensions.

Comment: @Jason Ah! It's unknown whether $\pi_n(S^2)$ is ever zero for $n>1$. I think one could probably write a tentative answer assuming it was; though perhaps one would need to assume $n$ odd. But it is also my impression that solving our case would solve (half of?) an open problem.

Comment: It seems my approach won't work to show a map is trivial, though.  What I show is that the long composition starting with $S^{2k+1}$ is homotopically non-trivial, from which it follows that all the maps in the composition are non-trivial.  The converse doesn't work, though.  The map $S^{2k+1}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^{k-1}$ can be homotpically trival, and factor through $\mathbb{C}P^k$, and then the map from $\mathbb{C}P^k\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^{k-1}$ can still be nontrivial.  For an absurd example, replace $S^{2k+1}$ by a disc $D$ with surjective map $D\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^k$.

Comment: Dear Mike, someone who quotes one of the most beautiful poems of the greatest French poet ever can't be all bad :-) Are you French ?

Comment: Dear @Georges, I appreciate the comment! I am unfortunately a monolingual American, but I have learned enough French to be able to read (but not write or speak...) the language with some difficulty. Given that some exceptional literature, poetry, and mathematics is all written in French, I find even the little mastery I have very valuable :)

Comment: Dear @Mike: thanks for the answer to my rather indiscreet question and bravo for your open attitude toward foreign poetry. Conversely , I am a great admirer of American literature: when I started to learn English I fell in love with Poe's poems, particularly *The Raven* and *Annabel Lee*, which I was very happy later to find again in Nabokov's wonderful *Lolita*.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe there is a nontrivial map $\mathbb{C}P^k\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^{k-1}$ when $k > 2$ is odd.  I don't know what happens when $k$ is even.

Consider the following composition $$S^{2k+1}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^k\rightarrow S^{2k}\rightarrow S^{2k-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^{k-1}$$ with $k$ odd, where I'll now describe all the maps.

The maps from the odd dimensional spheres to complex projective spaces are the Hopf maps, that is, they are the projections from the family of Hopf fibrations $$S^1\rightarrow S^{2n-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n.$$ The map from $\mathbb{C}P^k$ to $S^{2k}$ is obtained by collapsing the $2k-2$ skeleton of $\mathbb{C}P^k$ to a point, and the map from $S^{2k}$ to $S^{2k-1}$ generates $\pi_{2k}(S^{2k-1})$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ because $k > 1$.

I will prove the the composition $S^{2k+1}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^{k-1}$ is homotopically nontrivial, which will then imply the map from $\mathbb{C}P^{k}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^{k-1}$ is as well.

First, the long exact sequence in homotopy groups associated to the Hopf fibration above implies the projection map from $S^{2k-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^{k-1}$ is an isomorphism, except on $\pi_2$.  Hence, if the map $S^{2k+1}\rightarrow S^{2k-1}$ is nonzero as an element of $\pi_{2k+1}(S^{2k-1})$, the overall composition is nontrivial.

From [a previous question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308318/is-the-map-s2n1-rightarrow-mathbbcpn-rightarrow-mathbbcpn-mathbb), it follows that, when $k$ is odd, the composition $S^{2k+1}\rightarrow S^{2k}$ is the generator of $\pi_{2k+1}(S^{2k})$.

So, the map $S^{2k+1}\rightarrow S^{2k-1}$ is obtained by composing a generator of $\pi_{2k+1}(S^{2k})\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with a generator of $\pi_{2k}(S^{2k-1})\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

But, according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres, in the "Ring structure" portion, this composition is nontrivial.

Comment: Presumably, one can use more detailed knowledge of how elements of the homotopy groups of spheres compose to generate more examples.  Unfortunately, all I know of this topic I just learned from the wiki page I linked to.

Comment: This is quite nice. It's unfortunate that Wikipedia doesn't have a reference for the claim in the 'example', however.

Comment: I'm glad you like it!  http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/ravenel2.pdf, page 5 implies the part of the Wiki claim I used is actually true.  As an added bonus, using the element $\mu$ in the paper gives, by the same argument, a homotopically nontrivial map $\mathbb{C}P^k\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^{k-4}$ whenever $k\geq 10$.

Comment: (Two corrections to my previous comment:  I don't need the condition $k\geq 10$, it's valid as soon as it makes sense: $k\geq 5$.  But I still need $k$ odd.)

Comment: Ah, then that gives a map to $S^2$ like I was seeking. That settles it.

Comment: I appreciate your accepting this post, but I'd still love to see other examples, if others want to post them.  In particular, is there a homotopically nontrivial map $\mathbb{C}P^2\rightarrow S^2$?  I can prove there is one iff there is one from $\mathbb{C}P^2$ to $S^3$, but I'm stuck there.  I'll keep thinking about it.

Comment: Alright, I'll unaccept and add that particular question in the original post.

Comment: @Mike:  Thanks again for the bounty!

Answer (score 19):

I can prove that there at most $2$ homotopy classes of maps from $\mathbb{C}P^2$ to $\mathbb{C}P^1$.  However, I can't prove or disprove that there are exactly $2$.  Perhaps someone can answer the final question and finish this off?  (Or provide a completely different proof!)

I'll use the notation $[X,Y]$ to refer to homotopy classes of maps from $X$ to $Y$.

**Claim 1**:  Fix a space $X$ and suppose every map $f:X\rightarrow S^2$ induces a trivial map on $H^2$.  Then, the Hopf projection map $\pi:S^3\rightarrow S^2$ induces a bijection from $[X,S^3]$ to $[X,S^2]$.

Proof:  First, note that $f$ induces $0$ on $H^2$ iff there is a map $\tilde{f}:X\rightarrow S^3$ with $\pi\circ \tilde{f} = f$.  (I can supply a proof if desired).  Then the map which assigns to $f\in[X,S^2]$ the map $\tilde{f}\in [X,S^3]$ is the inverse of the map induced by $\pi$. $\square$

**Edit**  A proof that $f$ induces the $0$ map on $H^2$ iff it lifts *was* desired, and resulted in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918468/lifting-cohomology-killing-maps-through-the-3-sphere) question and answer.  **End edit**

**Claim 2**:  If $X = \mathbb{C}P^n$ with $n > 1$, then every map $f\in [X,S^2]$ is trivial on $H^2$.

Proof:  Look at the cohomology ring structure.  We have $H^\ast(\mathbb{C}P^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}[z]/z^{n+1}$ with $z$ in degree $2$.  If $x$ generates $H^2(S^2)$, then $f^\ast x = kz$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.  But then, since $x^2 = 0$, $0 = f^\ast (x^2) = (f^\ast x)^2 = k^2z^2$ which implies $k = 0$. $\square$

**Corollary**:  There is a bijection between $[\mathbb{C}P^n, S^2]$ and $[\mathbb{C}P^n,S^3]$ for any $n > 1$.

Now, we show there are at most 2 elements in $[\mathbb{C}P^2, S^3]$ for any $n$.  The main tool we use is the [Thom-Pontryagin construction](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7375/explanation-for-the-thom-pontryagin-construction-and-its-generalisations) which provides, for any closed manifold $X$, a bijection between $[X,S^k]$ for any $k$ and codimension $k$ closed framed submanifolds of $X$, modulo framed cobordism.  (A framed submanifold is a submanifold with trivial normal bundle, together with a choice of trivialization.  A framed cobordism $W$ between two framed manifolds $M_1$ and $M_2$ is a manifold with boundary $\partial W = M_1\coprod M_2$, together with trivialization of the normal bundle of $W$ which restricts to the chosen trivializations on $M_1$ and $M_2$)

Since we're focusing on $k=3$ and $\mathbb{C}P^2$, of dimension $4$, we're looking at codim 3, that is, $1$-dim closed submanifolds of $\mathbb{C}P^2$.  Recall that every $1$-d compact manifold is a disjoint union of a finite number of circles.

Given two embedded circles in $\mathbb{C}P^2$, there are obviously homotopic as $\pi_1(\mathbb{C}P^2) = 0$.  Whitney has proved that of you have two homotopic embeddings of $M$ into $N$ with $\dim N \geq 2\dim M + 2$, then they are isotopic.  The image of an isotopy is a cobordism between start and end times, so, we may assume wlog that any framed $1$-dim submanifold we are considering lives in a chart of $\mathbb{C}P^2$, that is, as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

**Claim 3**:  There are precisely two framed $1$-d submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^4$, up to framed cobordism.

Proof:  Since any framed cobordism is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$, it's still embedded into the compactification of $\mathbb{R}^4$, that is, of $S^4$.  By the Pontryagin-Thom construction, there is a bijection beteen $[S^4, S^3] = \pi_4(S^3) = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and framed $1$-d submanifolds of $S^4$ modulo framed cobordisms. $\square$

In $\mathbb{R}^4$, or $S^4$ representatives for the two framed cobordism classes are as follows.  First, one can use $S^1$ with a trivial parallel framing.  More specifically, using $S^1 = \{(\cos \theta, \sin \theta, 0,0)\}$, one can use the framing $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\} = \{ (\cos\theta, \sin\theta, 0,0), (0,0,1,0), (0,0,0,1)\}$.  Second, one can use $S^1$ with a once twisted framing.  More specifically, one can use the framing $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\} = \{ \cos \theta v_1 + \sin\theta v_2, -\sin\theta v_1 + \cos\theta v_2, v_3\}$.

Now, for the question.

> **Question**:  Thinking of both $S^1$s with framing as subsets of $\mathbb{R}^4\subseteq \mathbb{C}P^2$, is there a framed cobordism between them in $\mathbb{C}P^2$?

If so, then all maps from $\mathbb{C}P^2$ to $S^2$ are homotopically trivial.  If not, there is precisely one nontrivial map, up to homotopy.  Note that if such a cobordism exists, it must, by claim 3, not be contained in any chart of $\mathbb{C}P^2$.

Comment: Hi Jason, such great stuff here. What sort of argument do you have in mind for the claims in this and the next answer about factoring maps that kill second cohomology through bigger spheres?

Comment: @Kevin:  The answer is not particularly short.  So, I can either add a 4th answer to this question, or perhaps its worth just asking a new question on the main site?

Comment: OK, Jason, I've asked at question 918468, including what I think might be the beginning of your argument-but I don't see yet how you bring in the condition.

Comment: @MikeMiller:  Thank you for the bounty, you really didn't have to do that.  I'm not at all picky which you accept.  The only preference I'd have is to try to keep the three posts in order somehow (I don't know if this is possible), so perhaps you should put the bounty on the first post?  (With the current scores, if you accept the post about nontrivial maps $\mathbb{C}P^k\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^{k-1}$ with $k$ odd, then they'll be in the right order.  Who knows if they'll stay in the right order as scores change over time, though!)  Thanks again!

Comment: @JasonDeVito, see: Baues, H.J., *Obstruction Theory on Homotopy Classification of Maps'*, Lect. Notes in Math., **628**, Springer-Verlag, Berlin Heidelberg New York (1977). On (3.3.20) pg. 207, he claims *every map $\mathbb{C}P^2\to S^3$ or $S^2$ is null homotopic*.

Comment: @sigur:. Interesting.  Do you see a flaw in the argument I gave?  Or in the one Moishe did in the comments to my other answer?

Answer (score 17):

One person offering three answers to one post seems ludicrous (and this is a first for me), but I've really enjoyed this problem.

> **Theorem**:  There is a homotopically nontrivial map $\mathbb{C}P^2\rightarrow S^2$.

(By my second post, this map must be unique up to homotopy.)

We will prove this by answering the question in post 2.  Namely, we show that given the two framed $S^1\subseteq \mathbb{R}^4\subseteq \mathbb{C}P^2$ (which I'll denote $S^1_1$ and $S^1_2$) are NOT framed cobordant in $\mathbb{C}P^2$.  More specifically, given a framed cobordism between the two $S_i^1$s, we show we can lift the whole picture to $S^5$.  However, since $\pi_5(S^4) = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, the Pontryagin-Thom construction will imply that there is no such cobordism in $S^5$.

So, assume for a contradiction that there is such a cobordism $W$ between the $S_1^2$ and $S_2^1$.  Since $W$ is framed, the normal bundle is trivial.  Let $i:W\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^2$ denote the inclusion map.  Since $W$ is a surface with boundary, $H^2(W) = 0$, so the induced map $i^\ast:H^2(\mathbb{C}P^2)\rightarrow H^2(W)$ is trivial for trivial reasons.

By a small extension of Claim 1 from the second post, there is a lift $\tilde{i}:W\rightarrow S^5$, in the sense that $\pi\circ\tilde{i} = i$, where $\pi:S^5\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^2$ is the canonical projection.

Note that the normal bundle of $\tilde{i}(W)$ is the pullback under $\pi$ of the normal bundle to $W$, so is trivial.  In fact, a choice of trivialization of the normal bundle of $W$ induces one of $\tilde{i}(W)$ in the following fashion.  First, since $\pi\circ\tilde{i} = i$, it follows that $\tilde{i}(W)$ is transverse to the Hopf fibers.  In particular, if $V\in T_p S^5$ with $p\in \tilde{i}(W)$ denotes the vector field tangent to the Hopf vectors, then the projection of $V$ onto $T_p \tilde{i} W$, denote $\rho(V)$ is not the identity, so $V - \rho(V)$ is non-zero and normal to $\tilde{W}$.

To trivialize the rest of the normal bundle over $\tilde{i}(W)$, we start by embedding the normal bundle of $W$ into $\mathbb{C}P^2$ as a tubular neighborhood of $W$ (and I'll call this map $i$ as well).  This tubular neighborhood deformation retracts onto $W$, so $\tilde{i}$ extends to this neighborhood, and gives an embedding of the tubular neighborhood into $S^5.$  Then one can use this extended $\tilde{i}$ to transport a choice of trivialization of $W$ to one of $\tilde{i}(W).$

In particular, we have a framing on $\tilde{i}(W)$ given by taking framing given by the previous paragraph together with $V - \rho(V)$ $\tilde{i}(W)$.  Thus, $\tilde{i}(W)$ is a framed cobordism between $\tilde{i}(S_1^1)$ and $\tilde{i}(S_2^1)$.

But, there is no such framed cobordism.  The idea is that since both $S^1_i$ are in a small chart in $\mathbb{C}P^2$, their lifts to $S^5$ are given by essentially the same formulas (in an appropriate chart on $S^5$), together with $V - \rho(V)$.  According to post 2, under the Pontryagin-Thom construction, these are representatives from the two equivalence classes corresponding to the fact that $\pi_5(S^4)$ has exactly two elements.

This contradiction implies $W$ can't exist.  So, we've found at least two framed submanifolds of $\mathbb{C}P^2$ which are not framed cobordant.  By the Pontryagin-Thom construction, this implies $[\mathbb{C}P^2,S^2]$ has at least 2 elements.  In particular, there a homotopically nontrival map from $\mathbb{C}P^2$ to $S^2$.

$$ $$

If one traces through the Pontryagin-Thom construction, it follows that the following map $\mathbb{C}P^2\rightarrow S^2$ is homotopically nontrivial.  We first define it as a map into $S^3$, then compose with the Hopf map $S^3\rightarrow S^2$.

Consider the normal bundle $\nu$ of $S_2^1$, embedded into $\mathbb{C}P^2$, and once and for all, pick a point $p\in S^3$ and a basis $\{e_1,e_2, e_3\}$ of $T_p S^3$.  We map the entire $0$ section of $\nu$ to $p$.  Each fiber of $\nu$, isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$, is mapped onto $S^3$ with all points sufficiently far from the origin being mapped to $-p$ (think stereographics projection) and so that the differential maps the basis $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$ from Post 2 to the basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$.  Finally, map points of $\mathbb{C}P^2$ wich are not in $\nu\subseteq \mathbb{C}P^2$ to $-p$.

Comment: This is really a natural addendum to Post 2, but I think it makes sense to keep the separate just for length reasons.  Also, I suspect the same argument can be used to show $[\mathbb{C}P^k,\mathbb{C}P^{k-1}]$ consists of two elements for all $k$:  Use the cohomology ring to show that any map $f:\mathbb{C}P^k\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^{k-1}$ is trivial on $H^2$.  Thus, any such map lifts to $S^{2k-1}$.  Now, use Pontryagin-Thom as I did in this post.

Comment: Jason: I think, the way to identify this map is to take first the map $CP^2\to S^4$ (collapse $CP^1$ to a point) and then map $S^4$ to $CP^1=S^2$ using the nontrivial element of $\pi_4(S^2)\cong Z_2$. It is quite clear that the composition is homotopically nontrivial. Also, the fact that $\pi_4(S^2)\cong Z_2$ explains why one cannot get more than one nontrivial map this way.

Comment: @studiousus:  I would not at all be surprised if this map works, but it is unclear to me that the composition is homotopically nontrivial.  Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: Maybe I see it in after all.  By Kevin's answer, any map from $\mathbb{C}P^2\rightarrow S^2$ is homotpically trivial when restricted to $\mathbb{C}P^1$.  It should follow (does it?) that any map from $\mathbb{C}P^2\rightarrow S^2$, up to homotopy, factors through $\mathbb{C}P^2/\mathbb{C}P^1$.  But now there at most 2 such maps, since $\pi_4(S^2) = \mathbb{Z}_2$.  Since my post shows there are at least 2, your description must also be homotopically nontrivial.  (I'd still like to see it's nontrivial without using my answer, if you have the time.)

Comment: Jason: I do not have time, but the idea is that if you start with a map $f: CP^2\to CP^1$ which is homotopy-trivial on $CP_1\subset CP^2$, then this property persists under homotopy $F$ of $f$. This implies (with some work) that you can alter $F$ rel. $0\times CP^2$ and $1\times CP^2$, to make it literally constant on $CP^1\subset CP^2$. Now, apply nontriviality of $\pi_4(S^2)$.

Comment: @studiosus.  That makes perfect sense.  Thank you!

Comment: @MoisheKohan:  It seems that my above post is wrong (as initially pointed out by Sigur).  I'm not sure where exactly the mistake lies, but this answer directly contradicts https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306019/existence-of-non-null-homotopic-map-from-mn-to-sn-1?rq=1, as well as other known results.   But then I am confused about your comment (from 5 years ago!) giving another proof of the existence of an essential map.

Answer (score 5):

I seem to be able to argue via obstruction theory that there is no nontrivial map $\mathbb{C} P^2\to S^2$. That is, taking any map $f$ on the 2-skeleton $\mathbb{C}P^1\subset \mathbb{C}P^2$, $f$ extends to the 4-skeleton iff the cellular cochain that takes the unique 4-cell $e_4$ to the homotopy class of $f|_{\partial e_4}$ is trivial in $C^4(\mathbb{C} P^2;\pi_3(S^2))$. If $f$ is of degree $1$, then $f(e_4)=1\in\pi_3(S^2)$, where $1$ is the Hopf map, since the 4-cell of $\mathbb{C} P^2$ is attached via the Hopf map. Then if $f$ is of degree $n$, it maps the 4-cell to $n$. Thus the obstruction is insurmountable except in case $n=0$.

The problem with this argument is that it will show that there are no maps from $\mathbb{C}P^n$ to $\mathbb{C}P^1$ for any $n>1$, and Jason deVito's comment to his first answer indicates there is one for $n=5$.

Comment: I must confess I really know nothing of obstruction theory, but what is $C^4$?  Also, again, I'm not an expert, but it seems as though your argment simply shows the degree of $f$, when restricted to $\mathbb{C}P^1$, must be $0$.  I don't understand why this implies every extension of $f$ is null homotopic.  (For example, apply this to the essential Hopf map $S^3\rightarrow S^2$ where $S^3$ is given the inductive skeleton of $2$ cells of each dimension up to $3$.    Since the map on $S^2\subseteq S^3$ extends to all of $S^3$, the degree of the Hopf map, when restricted to $S^2$ is $0$.)

Comment: Ah, yes, you've fixed it: I think I was subconsciously assuming some uniqueness to an extension, which one doesn't have at all. Thanks! For what it's worth by $C^4$ I just mean the cellular cochain group. I haven't really used much obstruction theory here: just the notion that a map extends over a disk if and only if it's nullhomotopic on the boundary.

Comment: I'd love to learn obstruction theory (and many other things) some day!  Any favorite references?  Anyway, thanks for the input.  I actually think I've answered my question above, but I still need time to get the details right before posting/editing.

Comment: I think Davis and Kirk's lecture notes on algebraic topology are a good way to get a first exposure to a wide range of relatively advanced tools in the subject. They take a pretty classical tack, which is nice for concrete geometric applications, but May's second book might be a good supplement from a more cutting-edge viewpoint.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll check those out whenever I get some time.

Comment: @KevinCarlson, so *there is no nontrivial map* should be edited, if I understood.